# SignalR - Push notifications to Silverlight from outside Http context

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-5.0, signalr, httpcontext, signalr-hub

I'm new to SignalR and am trying send push notifications to a Silverlight client.

Our web project is NOT Asp.Net MVC - just ASP.NET.

I have created a simple Hub class:

```
 [HubName("ServerHub")] 
public class ServerHub: Hub
{
    public Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        return Clients.NewMessage(message);
    }
}
```

The problem is that we've got some messages coming through to our web server via message queues (Rhino Service Bus). When a message is processed, we want to send a notification to the UI. But the RSB worker thread is running outside of the HttpContext, so when invoking the SendMessage method the Clients property is null.

I have tried to work around this by adding the ServerHub to the Http Cache, and then retrieve it from the Message Consumer. Still having same issue - Hub's properties are null.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, was doing it wrong.
Hadn't used GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve().

Regards.